# Magento 2 Add a global js function

Tags: module, theme, custom

i'm trying to extend Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/class, in magento 2.4.3-p1, from a module but my extend js doesn't load in page
here is my /view/frontend/web/require-config.js

```
var config = {
config: {
    mixins: {
        'Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/class': {
            'My_CustomModule/js/globalfunction': true
        },
    }
}
};
```

here my js /view/frontend/web/js/globalfunction.js

```
define(['Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/class'], function (Class) {
'use strict';
console.log('Extend starting');
});
```

I have also try to delete every type of cache, the deploy mode is set to developer so i don't need to compile the di, also i included Magento_Ui in module.xml .

How i can achieve this?